# Hive Catalog Table - Need "table" with list of tables and columns

Tags: hive, hql

Is there anything you can query in hive that has similar data as SYS.OBJECTS and SYS.COLUMNS in SQL server?

Thanks,

Craig

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of tables, you can query

```
SHOW TABLES;
```

Then to get the details of a single table:

```
DESCRIBE TABLE_NAME;
```

Comment: Yes but im looking for a system table that can has all tables and all columns associated.  Theoretically i can search by table name and get all the columns and types.

Comment: Since Hive stores this information in its metastore, e.g. MySql, you could connect to the MySql db directly and query that? There is no such Sysobjects table through Hive